# PagedList<MessageItem> Recycler view group by field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagedlist

In my RecyclerView i display some data that i get from my Database.

```
var chatRoomContactMessages: LiveData<PagedList<MessageItem>> =
        Transformations.switchMap(contactItem) {
            it?.let {
                val itemFactory = messagesRepository.getChatRoomMessages(
                    serverId,
                    it.contactId
                ).map { messageItem: ChatMessageItem? ->
                        // Function that creates a messageItem from the query result row
                        toMessageChatItem(messageItem, it.accountId)
                }

                LivePagedListBuilder(
                    contactItemFactory, pagedListConfig
                ).build()
            }
        }
```

With that way i get the data from database and apply a Transformation.map to each item in order to convert it to the proper object for the adapter.

My problem is that i want to group this list of item by a field of the messageItem (messageItem.msgDate) because in the recyclerView i want to show a specific item_layout when the day changes.
So i guess i must add some more "MessageItems" that indicate to the recycler to add the item_layout.

How can i do this??

Comment: Might want to add your item_layout.xml and a bit more code to help piece together what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean...